# How to plot line graph with a certain break of year variable in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I want to plot a line graph with continuous years on x axis from 1990 to 2005.

```
# I create a dataframe as below and try to plot as a line graph. 

year<-c(1990:2005)

num<-c(3,2,4,7,6,22,9,31,12,30,17,23,21,36,41,21)

df<-data.frame(year,num)

str(df)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=year,y=num)) + geom_line() + theme_bw() + ylab("Number") +  xlab("Year") + geom_point()
```

This above plot does not give x axis from 1990, 1991, 1992,...,2005 as I want it to be. (not 1990, 1995, 2000,2005).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out `scale_x_continuous()` - there is an option `breaks` inside which you can set to whatever you like. something like `breaks = seq(1990,2005,1)` should do.

Comment: Thanks so much @davidski

Comment: glad it helped. for general axis/labels related questions you can refer to the `scale_*_*()` functions in the docs. here is also a [cheat sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf) for quick reference. also, pls consider marking this as solved - if my answer did indeed solve your question.